# Protected constructor and accessibility

Tags: java, constructor

Why can't we instantiate a class with a protected constructor if its child is in a different package? If protected variables and methods can be accessed, why doesn't the same rule also apply for a protected constructor?

pack1:

```
package pack1;

public class A {
    private int a;
    protected int b;
    public int c;

    protected A() {    
        a = 10;
        b = 20;
        c = 30;
    }
}
```

pack2:

```
package pack2;

import pack1.A;

class B extends A {
    public void test() {
        A obj = new A(); // gives compilation error; why?
        //System.out.println("print private not possible :" + a);
        System.out.println("print protected possible :" + b);
        System.out.println("print public possible :" + c);
    }
}

class C {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A a = new A(); // gives compilation error; why?
        B b = new B();
        b.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please make an effort to construct your question clearly, format it properly, and tag it appropriately. You have not done any of these.

Comment: its clear.. parent A and child B are in two different packages(pack1 and pack2 respectively).. why compiler errors while creating an object of a class(parent A) whose constructor is protected ?

Comment: I believe that instead of accessing `b` from the actual instance, if this had `obj.b` (assuming obj was created or passed successfully) it would also give a compilation error

Answer (score 24):

According to the Java Spec (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.2)

> #### 6.6.2.2. Qualified Access to a `protected` Constructor
>
> Let `C` be the class in which a `protected` constructor is declared and let `S` be the innermost class in whose declaration the use of the `protected` constructor occurs. Then:
>
> - If the access is by a superclass constructor invocation `super(...)`, or a qualified superclass constructor invocation `E.super(...)`, where `E` is a *Primary* expression, then the access is permitted.
> - If the access is by an anonymous class instance creation expression `new C(...){...}`, or a qualified anonymous class instance creation expression `E.new C(...){...}`, where `E` is a *Primary* expression, then the access is permitted.
> - **If the access is by a simple class instance creation expression `new C(...)`, or a qualified class instance creation expression `E.new C(...)`, where `E` is a *Primary* expression, or a method reference expression `C :: new`, where `C` is a *ClassType*, then the access is not permitted.** A `protected` constructor can be accessed by a class instance creation expression (that does not declare an anonymous class) or a method reference expression only from within the package in which it is defined.

In your case, access to the protected constructor of `A` from `B` would be legal from a constructor of `B` through an invocation of `super()`. However, access using `new` is not legal.

Answer (score 10):

JLS  6.6.7 answers your question. A subclass only access a protected members of its parent class, if it involves implementation of its parent. Therefore , you can not instantiate a parent object in a child class, if parent constructor is protected and it is in different package...

> 6.6.7 Example: protected Fields, Methods, and Constructors Consider
>   this example, where the points package
>   declares:

```
package points;
public class Point {
    protected int x, y;
    void warp(threePoint.Point3d a) {
        if (a.z > 0)        // compile-time error: cannot access a.z
            a.delta(this);
    }
}
```

> and the threePoint package declares:

```
package threePoint;
import points.Point;
public class Point3d extends Point {
    protected int z;
    public void delta(Point p) {
        p.x += this.x;      // compile-time error: cannot access p.x
        p.y += this.y;      // compile-time error: cannot access p.y
    }
    public void delta3d(Point3d q) {
        q.x += this.x;
        q.y += this.y;
        q.z += this.z;
    }
}
```

> which defines a class Point3d. A
>   compile-time error occurs in the
>   method delta here: it cannot access
>   the protected members x and y of its
>   parameter p, because while Point3d
>   (the class in which the references to
>   fields x and y occur) is a subclass of
>   Point (the class in which x and y are
>   declared), it is not involved in the
>   implementation of a Point (the type of
>   the parameter p). The method delta3d
>   can access the protected members of
>   its parameter q, because the class
>   Point3d is a subclass of Point and is
>   involved in the implementation of a
>   Point3d. The method delta could try to
>   cast (§5.5, §15.16) its parameter to
>   be a Point3d, but this cast would
>   fail, causing an exception, if the
>   class of p at run time were not
>   Point3d.
>
> A compile-time error also occurs in
>   the method warp: it cannot access the
>   protected member z of its parameter a,
>   because while the class Point (the
>   class in which the reference to field
>   z occurs) is involved in the
>   implementation of a Point3d (the type
>   of the parameter a), it is not a
>   subclass of Point3d (the class in
>   which z is declared).

Comment: constructor is also a member of class, isn't it?

Comment: Actually, no it isn't.  A constructor is NOT a member.  And these are not the rules that apply in this case.  The real applicable rules are in JLS 6.6.2.2 - see @mazaneicha's answer.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with previous posters, don't know why you would want to do this (instantiate parent in that way in extending class) but you could even do something like this:

```
public void test() {
    A obj = new A(){}; // no compilation error; why? you use anonymous class 'override'
    ...
```

Comment: just be aware that obj is not a (direct) instance of class `A`, it is an instance of an anonymous subclass of `A`

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need `A obj=new A();` in class, whereas object of class b is itself an object of `class A`

And in class c it is giving error because, you are accessing the protected property of class A which is constructor.

To  get object of class A in this case you must use this function in class A

```
static A getInstance()
{
   A obj = new A(); // create obj of type A.
   return obj; // returns that object by this method. No need to use 'New' kind of instantiation.
}
```

Comment: constructor of class A is protected. So you can not create object of class A, anywhere else except in class A. So add a static function in class, which will give object of class A.

Comment: FYI , we can create an object of class A anywhere in the same package!! and what do you mean by  1.object of class b is itself an object of class A and 2.in class c it is giving error because, you are accessing the protected property of class A which is constructor .. you only wrote this..!!!

Comment: Protected properties are not accessible out of class itself and child classes. But you are creating object of class A in class C. And class is not related to class A.  Whenever you create a object of class it calls constructor of that class. I don't know too much about JAVa, but know OOP.

Comment: for a decorator and to prevent direct instanciation for instance.

Answer (score 1):

> If protected variables and methods can be accessed, why doesn't the same rule also apply for a protected constructor?

Protected variables and methods can only be accessed if the child class in another package **extends** the class containing the protected variables and methods.
You are able to access variable '**b**' in child class B because you have extended the class A. You will not be able to access variable '**b**' in class C as it is not extending class A.

The only way to access protected constructor in child class is by using parent class reference variable and child class object.

```
package pack2;

import pack1.A;

class B extends A {
    public void test() {
        A obj = new B(); // will execute protected constructor
        System.out.println("print protected possible :" + b);
    }
}
```