# Why can't I define interface for overlay type lightweight collections?

Tags: gwt, interface, overlay

I want to define an interface for lightweight collections as blow, but it can't be compiled successfully. Any mistake here?

```
//...........................Interface...........................................

@SingleJsoImpl(JsArrayExtImpl.class)
public interface JsArrayExt<M>{

        public  void add(int addBefore, M model) ;

        public  void add(M model) ;

        public  void addAll(JsArrayExt<M> models);
}


//................................Implementation

public class JsArrayExtImpl<M extends JavaScriptObject> extends JsArray<M> implements    JsArrayExt<M>
{
  protected JsArrayExtImpl()
  {
  }

  @Override
  public final native void add(int addBefore, M model) /*-{
    this.splice(addBefore, 0, model);
  }-*/;

  @Override
  public final void add(M model)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "Code server for gwttest from Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:13.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/13.0.1 on ...GWTTest.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 @ SR;E74|oFVbz;?F%" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.dispose(ModuleSpace.java:146)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:215)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)`
```

Comment: Could you add the compilator error?

Comment: yep,added,not so much useful message

Answer (score 0):

This is because JsArray has a protected constructor. See: [Protected constructor and accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150748/protected-constructor-and-accessibility)

You can't subclass it. You'll need to copy the code into your own class.

Comment: JsArray can be subclassed,I did it in my code base,and works.

Comment: Don't think that's it, that rule is for use of "new Superclass()" not "super()".