# Pass data by hostpage error:JavaScriptObject$ cannot be cast to com.pkg.model

Tags: javascript, gwt, casting

I followed this article to use hostpage to pass an array to client:

```
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/dynamic_host_page
```

Currently,I can see follow content in firebug

```
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
<head>
......
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var rcmdFriends=[{"Name":"Friend-0","Image":"url"}];
    </script>
</head>
......
</html>
```

Then I tried to use these code to get js variable(a json array actually) from hostpage and print it to user:

```
    //get array from host page
private native JsArrayExt<People> getRecommendedFriends()/*-{
    return $wnd.rcmdFriends;
}-*/;

@Override
public void onModuleLoad()
{
    final FlowPanel fPanel = new FlowPanel();
    JsArrayExt<People> channels = getRecommendedFriends();
    for (int i = 0, len = channels.length(); i < len; i++)
    {
                 //"print" name to user
         fPanel.add(new Label(channels.get(i).getName()));
    }
    RootPanel.get().add(fPanel);
}

    //model definition
    @SingleJsoImpl(PeopleImpl.class)
    public interface People extends HasName
    {
        String getImage();
        void setImage(String Image);
    }
```

But got this eror:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject$ cannot be cast to com.pkg.People
```

Strangely,I can already see the length of "channels" is 1,and why do I get this casting error?How to solove this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast to an ordinary Java pojo. You must implement an [overlay type](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsOverlay)

```
public class PersonJSON extends JavaScriptObject {

    protected PersonJSON() {
    }

    public final native String getName() /*-{
        return this.Name;
    }-*/;

    public final native String getImage() /*-{
        return this.Image;
    }-*/;
}
```

Then you can call

```
JsArray<PersonJSON> channels = getRecommendedFriends();
```

and read out the values from the PersonJSON elements;

Comment: Well, he *is* using a JSO (see `@SingleJsoImpl` annotation)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `JsArrayExt` is the interface from [Why can't I define interface for overlay type lightweight collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202382/116472), I suppose that the fact you do not use an explicit JSO subclass confuses the DevMode.

Because you directly call a JSNI method, I don't understand why you don't use a `JsArrayExtImpl<PersonImpl>` which I believe would Just Work™; there's no point in using the interfaces here.

If you really can't make it work, I'd suggest using AutoBeans instead (it unfortunately requires a small serialize/parse dance in DevMode: `AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, Person.class, new JSONObject(rawJso).toString())`, whereas in prod mode you can simply use `AutoBeanCodex.decode(factory, Person.class, (JsoSplittable) rawJso)`). In your case, it'd require another *dance* because you're using an array as the *root* object; see [GWT Autobean - how to handle lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13651068/116472)

Comment: Ok, never used @SingleJsoImpl, live and learn. But my solution will work without much hassle.