# Access modifiers for filter streams in Java

Tags: java, oop, io

I am learning object-oriented programming and right now also Java's basic IO.

What is the reasoning behind the constructors of `FilterInputStream` and `FilterOutputStream`
being protected and package private respectively? (Why are they not public and why are they different?)

Comment: The same reason for any other class. Restrict the usage , out side the package.

Answer (score 0):

See this could help!!
Usage of access specifiers.[image]

Comment: @sureshatta Why should you want to restrict usage of a constructor to inside a package and why the stricter access to the `FilterOutputStream` constructor to the `FilterInputStream` constructor?

Comment: @RobertRoman if you don't want other classes(In other package and NON_Subclass) to instantiate your particular class you can make your constructor protected.
You can checkout this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150748/protected-constructor-and-accessibility
It would help.