# Why can't I use protected constructors outside the package?

Tags: java, protected, access-modifiers

Why can't I use protected constructors outside the package for this piece of code:

```
package code;
public class Example{
    protected Example(){}
    ...
}
```

Check.java

```
package test;
public class Check extends Example {
  void m1() {
     Example ex=new Example(); //compilation error
  }
}
```

1. Why do i get the error even though i have extended the class?
   Please explain

**EDIT:**

Compilation error:

> The constructor Example() is not visible

Comment: Knowing the compilation error could be quite useful in diagnosing the problem...

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150748/protected-constructor-and-accessibility you can use a protected constructor of a superclass in the constructor of a subclass but not to instantiate a superclass instance Anywhere else.

Comment: More or less the same reason you can't do `public class Example {protected int i;} /* in another package: */ public class Check extends Example {void m1(Example ex) {ex.i = 2;}}`

Comment: The choice of duplicate question is unfortunate, since these two questions, while related, are distinct, and the other question doesn’t answer this one at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

protected modifier is used only with in the package and in sub-classes outside the package. When you create a object using `Example ex=new Example();` it will call parent class constructor by default.

As parent class constructor being protected you are getting a compile time error. You need to call the protected constructor according to JSL 6.6.2.2 as shown below in example 2.

```
package Super;

public class SuperConstructorCall {

    protected SuperConstructorCall() {
    }

}

package Child;

import Super.SuperConstructorCall;

public class ChildCall extends SuperConstructorCall
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SuperConstructorCall s = new SuperConstructorCall(); // Compile time error saying SuperConstructorCall() has protected access in SuperConstructorCall
    }
}
```

Example 2 conforming to [JLS 6.6.2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2.2):

```
package Super;

    public class SuperConstructorCall {

    protected SuperConstructorCall() {
    }

}

package Child;

import Super.SuperConstructorCall;

public class ChildCall extends SuperConstructorCall
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SuperConstructorCall s = new SuperConstructorCall(){}; // This will work as the access is by an anonymous class instance creation expression 
    }
}
```

Comment: No. `protected` can be used across packages. You just have to extend the class. `default` scope is *within a package*. **The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.**

Comment: Still the answer is not convincing, I understand that it will call the parent class consturtor ie> Example() which is protected but as we know we can use protected modifers outside the package if we extend that class then why that doesn't work here in case of constructors?

Comment: Why would you need to call the constructor of a superclass independently? You have access to methods of superclass directly if they are not default access or private.

Answer (score 14):

Usually `protected` means only accessible to subclasses or classes in the same package. However here are the rules for constructors from the JLS:

> 6.6.2.2. Qualified Access to a protected Constructor
>
> Let C be the class in which a protected constructor is declared and
>   let S be the innermost class in whose declaration the use of the
>   protected constructor occurs. Then:
>
> If the access is by a superclass constructor invocation super(...),
>   or a qualified superclass constructor invocation E.super(...), where E
>   is a Primary expression, then the access is permitted.
>
> If the access is by an anonymous class instance creation expression
>   new C(...){...}, or a qualified anonymous class instance creation
>   expression E.new C(...){...}, where E is a Primary expression, then
>   the access is permitted.
>
> If the access is by a simple class instance creation expression new
>   C(...), or a qualified class instance creation expression E.new
>   C(...), where E is a Primary expression, or a method reference
>   expression C :: new, where C is a ClassType, then the access is not
>   permitted. A protected constructor can be accessed by a class instance
>   creation expression (that does not declare an anonymous class) or a
>   method reference expression **only from within the package in which it
>   is defined.**

As an example, this does not compile

```
public class Example extends Exception {

    void method() {
        Exception e = new Exception("Hello", null, false, false);
    }
}
```

but this does

```
public class Example extends Exception {

    Example() {
        super("Hello", null, false, false);
    }
}
```

and so does this

```
public class Example {

    void method() {
        Exception e = new Exception("Hello", null, false, false) {};
    }
}
```

So the rules are clear, but I can't say I understand the reasons behind them!

Comment: learned new thing ;)

Comment: @kittu So did I. I didn't realise there were weird restrictions like that.

Answer (score 3):

In fact you are already using protected constructor of Example because Check has an implicit constructor and implicit Example constructor call:

```
public Check() {
    super();
}
```