# why protected constructor can't be called in child class in another package? Am I right about my logic?

Tags: java, constructor, extends, protected

```
package 1;
public class Father{
  protected Father(){
    System.out.println("This is Father");
  }
  protected void print(){
    System.out.println("This is print() from Father")
  }
}

package 2;
import 1.Father;
public class Son extends Father{
  Son(){
    System.out.println("This is Son");
    print();
    Father father = new Father();   //Error:The constructor Father() is not visible
  }
public static void main(String args[]){
    Son son = new Son();                   
}
```

I understand that, since they are not in the same package, `protected` method can only be seen in an extending class(here `Son`), but why a `protected` method `print()` can be called while `protected` constructor can not?

EDIT:
I kind of get logic behind this. `protected` is seen either (1)in the same package or (2) child class in other package. Now when I call `new Father()`,error comes:

For (1) `new Father()` is not called in the same package. Error!
For (2) Since constructor is not inherited, there is no `parent` constructor existing in `child class`. Error!

So we can use super() to refer to the constructor in parent class, which is a fix method for case(2).(There is no way to fix (1) because I already put `parent class` and `child class` into 2 different packages!OK...There is one way, change protected to public, which is too obvious to see)

Comment: Actually, that is not a good dup link.  The linked question is about access to protected members.  A constructor is not a member ... and the access rules are **different** for constructors.  (I learned something today!)

Comment: This (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150748/protected-constructor-and-accessibility) would a better Q&A ... except that the "best" answer gives an incorrect explanation.

Comment: @StephenC You're right. Please update as appropriate.

Comment: *"(There is no way to fix (1) because I already put parent class and child class into 2 packages!)"*  - Two ways.  1) change the packaging.  2) make the constructor for `Father` public.  But apart from that, you can't violate the JLS rules.  (See linked Q&A and specifically the answer by @mazaneicha)

Comment: @Stephe C Thanks...So am I right about where error comes?

Comment: Not exactly.  The >>real<< reason is that the JLS explicitly forbids this.  The real rationale for the JLS rules is not spelled out in the JLS, but your attempt does not convince me.  :-)

Comment: @Stephen C OK, I get it! I can't argue over "explicitly forbids" .